# CookieError: Illegal Key

Tags: cookies, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing a web crawler in aiohttp and experiencing a problem with cookies. Server I'm trying to crawl requires authentication and in order to fetch pages available to authenticated users I need to set a cookie with brackets in the key itself. This is a problem as `aiohttp.ClientSession.cookie_jar.update_cookies` either ignores any illegal cookies:

```
session = ClientSession()
cookie = SimpleCookie("a[b]=1234;")
session.cookie_jar.update_cookies(cookie)
print([f for f in session.cookie_jar])  # empty list, cookie not set
```

or raises a `CookieError`:

```
session = ClientSession()
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie["a[b]"] = "1234"  # http.cookies.CookieError: Illegal key 'a[b]'
session.cookie_jar.update_cookies(cookie)
print([f for f in session.cookie_jar])


session = ClientSession()
session.cookie_jar.update_cookies([("a[b]", "1234")])  # http.cookies.CookieError: Illegal key 'a[b]'
print([f for f in session.cookie_jar])
```

---

It is possible to force setting the cookie by accessing `http.cookies.Morsel`'s protected member `_key`, i.e.

```
session = ClientSession()
session.cookie_jar.update_cookies([("__tmp", "1234")])
for cookie in session.cookie_jar:
    if cookie.key == "__tmp":
        cookie._key = "a[b]"
print([f for f in session.cookie_jar])  # invalid cookie is set correctly
```

but this only pushes the problem one step back, as any session request e.g. `session.get(url)`starts raising `http.cookies.CookieError`.

I cannot get around sending this cookie. Am I stuck using non async libraries like `requests` or is there a way to ignore this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround, and while I dislike using it, it was preferred solution over rewriting entire `aiohttp`:

```
import sys
if "http" in sys.modules:
    raise ImportError("Crawler must be imported before http module")
import http.cookies
http.cookies._is_legal_key = lambda _: True
```

Comment: I'm not happy about a monkeypatch either, but I'll take it.  For reference, there's been an issue open for several years on this point: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2683

Answer (score -1):

`aiohttp.CookieJar` is modeled to follow corresponding RFC specifications. Why it should process *illegal* cookie names?

Comment: While I appreciate it following the specifications, should it really be expected that every server on the internet is also following them? Should there not be an exception for such situations? Web browsers seem to be designed to accept illegal cookie names.

Comment: While this is a good point, a follow-up question is not an answer